# Map or apply a function to single value - the proper way to do in Python 3

Tags: python, iterator

In my python project, im many places appears the functionality strict equivalent to:

```
def map_or_single(item,func, iterative_classes, *args ):

   if isinstance(item, iterative_classes):
       for k in item:
           func(k, *args)
       return
   func(item, *args)
```

but i am sure there must be some Python (3 ?) built-in function for this trivial task, i dont want to invent a bycicle and use this crap in the project. Anyone know  the proper build-in function for that ?

Comment: People commonly ask how to do things like this. The *right* thing to do is make the caller responsible for wrapping a single item in a list, rather than trying to accommodate inputs of two completely different types.

Comment: and if:
- you dont want to create a list if there is only one element there, just for performance stuff?
- or you have some kind of tree/graph structure, where leafes are non-lists and branches are lists?

Comment: Creating a singleton list isn't going to be significantly more expensive than the type sniffing you already have. Python doesn't have anything like the `Functor` type class in Haskell, which lets you map over a value in a structure-preserving way.

Comment: guess i need to provide the example why its needed, moment...

Comment: so if you have like  a map where values can be lists or not, just make those to single lists?

Comment: Just for the direct argument to the function. Consider `mapper(f, [1, 2, [3, 4], 5])`. It's none of `mapper`'s concern that the iterable argument consists of `int`s and `list`s. All it does is apply `f` to each element of the iterable. It's up to `f` to know how to handle each type as *its* input.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to write this at all. Instead of

```
map_or_single(item, func, ...)
```

just write

```
def mapper(func, items, *args):
    for k in items:
        func(k, *args)
```

`mapper` *always* takes a list (or some other iterable); it's up to the *caller* to provide one if necessary.

```
mapper(f, [1,2,3,4])
mapper(f, [1])  # Not mapper(f, 1)
mapper(f, some_tree_object.depth_first_iterator())
mapper(f, some_tree_object.breadth_first_iterator())
```

Comment: no , idefinitely have a nested structure where item can be either list or not

Comment: If it's nested, the iterator destroys that structure. All you get is a linear stream of elements from it.

Comment: no , it will be depth first search (and function apply) then

Comment: That's handled entirely by the iterator for `items`; `mapper` won't care about it.

Comment: `mapper` itself is pretty trivial. It's *so* trivial, in fact, that there's little reason to define it. It's just a combination of `map` and `partial`: `mapper(f, itr, *args) == map(partial(f, *args), itr)`, and like any use of `map` solely for the side effects, you are better off writing an explicit `for` loop yourself.

Comment: Gah, take my last comment with a grain of salt. `partial(f, *args)(k)` makes `k` the *last* positional argument to `f`, not the first. As long as `mapper` doesn't create a throwaway list of results, it should not be further confused with the similarly named `map` :)

Comment: is it a way to set the position of  an argument in partial?

Comment: Only if you use keyword arguments; positional arguments are filled strictly from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear [antipattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?AntiPattern), therefore there is no "proper" or "correct" way to do this in Python (or most, if not all other languages). You most certainly can come up with a wide variety of brittle solutions, but this is the type of thing that leads to bugs in the long term for very little benefit.

This problem is solved by avoiding this pattern altogether and requiring user input to conform to one pattern instead of two or more.

Instead of this interface:

```
map_or_single(single, func, ...)
map_or_single(iterable, func, ...)
```

You have this interface:

```
map_or_single([single], func, ...)
map_or_single(iterable, func, ...)
```

Requiring single values to be wrapped is a small price to pay to avoid all the potential headaches that can easily result from this pattern.

And obviously if the situation permits:

```
func(single)
map(func, iterable)
```

Comment: This is basically no different from my answer.

Comment: Although I provide an example of simply wrapping single inputs, that is not the main point I am driving home with my answer. I could have listed off a handful more examples of different ways to get around this issue, but the point is that this type of pattern should be avoided for long term quality and replaced with essentially anything else. The splat operator, wrapping single inputs in a list, writing two separate functions for a single or multiple value, use of the builtin map,  etc. are all ways that this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there's no one-liner builtin for this. I have this helper function in my project;

```
def any2list(val):
    if isinstance(val, (str, bytes)):
        val = [val]
    try:
        iter(val)
    except TypeError:
        val = [val]
    return list(val)
```

The goal of this function is to convert any input to a `list`. If a single element is given, it returns a list of this one element.

I use this in other functions like so,

```
def map_or_single(container, func, *args):
    container = any2list(container)
    for k in container:
        func(k, *args)
```

and now the `container` argument may be a proper container type (like `list`) or it might be a single element (scalar) like an `int`. I find this strategy pretty clean as I do not explicitly worry about the single element case.

Note: I choose to treat `str`s and `bytes` specially, so that `any2list` does not split a word or sentence into individual letters, which is almost always what I want. Your use cases might be different.

Comment: basiclyi would do  :

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions `map()` and `partial()`:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import add

l = [1, 2, 3]

result = map(partial(add, 2), l)

print(list(result))
# [3, 4, 5]
```